# How to extarct string between two square bracket Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have string like this:

```
jsonArray:
{
d = "[{\"Training_Code\":\"1234      \",\"Training_Duration\":\"2hrs      \",\"Training_Startdate\":\"14/02/2013 15:00:00\",\"Training_Enddate\":\"14/02/2013 17:00:00\",\"Trainer_ID\":1,\"Training_Location\":\"B-Wing Training room-4\",\"Comments\":\"C# training\",\"Keyword\":\"C#1234\",\"NumberofDays\":1},{\"Training_Code\":\"4321      \",\"Training_Duration\":\"16        \",\"Training_Startdate\":\"17/02/2013 10:30:00\",\"Training_Enddate\":\"17/02/2013 17:30:00\",\"Trainer_ID\":2,\"Training_Location\":\"A-Wing Training Room-6\",\"Comments\":\"Objective-C\",\"Keyword\":\"Obj-C4321\",\"NumberofDays\":2}]";
}
```

I want to get the data between two square bracket(including square bracket) and then remove all the "\" to get my final string like this:

```
[
{
"Training_Code": "1234",
"Training_Duration": "2hrs",
"Training_Startdate": "14/02/201315: 00: 00",
"Training_Enddate": "14/02/201317: 00: 00",
"Trainer_ID": 1,
"Training_Location": "B-WingTrainingroom-4",
"Comments": "C#training",
"Keyword": "C#1234",
"NumberofDays": 1
},
{
"Training_Code": "4321",
"Training_Duration": "16",
"Training_Startdate": "17/02/201310: 30: 00",
"Training_Enddate": "17/02/201317: 30: 00",
"Trainer_ID": 2,
"Training_Location": "A-WingTrainingRoom-6",
"Comments": "Objective-C",
"Keyword": "Obj-C4321",
"NumberofDays": 2
}
]
```

How can I do this in objective-c? thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the first code listing? I'm assuming `d` is `const char*` or else the `jsonArray {...}` section is also part of the JSON  string, and you've omitted the enclosing "".

Comment: Is your first code listing what gets printed to the console?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `JSONKit`([ref](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)) or `NSJSONSerialization` ([ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)), they will give either an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, depending on the structure of the JSON string.

---

**UPDATE**:

`d` looks like a well formed JSON string, but where is it coming from? Is it a `char[]` (as mentioned in the coments above), `NSString`, or console output?

It looks from here that your first code listing is what gets printed to the console. Printing JSON strings to the console will usually print the escape characters (`\`). In your other post, you are assuming every response can be parsed into an array. It would be safer to store the returned object into an `id` first, then check its class:

```
id rawData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonParsingError

if ( jsonParsingError != nil ) {
    // investigate the parsing error
}
else if ( [rawData isKindOfClass[NSDictionary class]] ) {
    NSDictionary *dict = rawData;
    //  process dictionary
}
else if ( [rawData isKindOfClass[NSArray class]] ) {
    NSArray *array = rawData;
    // process array
}
else {
    // some thing went completely wrong
}
```

You also do not indicate that you are checking any possible errors. Inspecting `jsonParsingError` will likely give clues as to what is going on.

Comment: I'm using NSJSONSerialization.Please look into my another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961239/posting-http-json-request-using-nsjsonserializer-ios ; I do not understand why I'm getting wrong data.I just wanted to make this correct...If you could please help.

Comment: @bapirout Looked at your other post, but you never show anything past the parsing operation. Also, if you could bring all relevant info into this question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use nsstring method `dataUsingEncoding` to get a nsdata instance.
2. Use `NSJSONSerialization`

The string you wanted is same as you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Since d is a string:

To remove "\" , you could this:

```
NSString *newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\" withString:@""];
```

Since the square brackets are at the front and the end, maybe you could do this:

```
[newString removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[newString removeObjectAtIndex:[newString count]-1];
```

first step is to get that string according to your situation and replace myString with your string.

Comment: That doesn't compile. The first `\` acts as an escape character, so the first string isn't terminated and the second parameter is read as part of the string. You can see this in the code coloring. @"\\" might work depending on what's really in his string - whether those slashes are real chars or escapes

Comment: Use a RegularExpression to find the data between the square brackets.

Comment: This would be the search string for RegEx `\[(.*?)\]`

Answer (score 0):

Only if the source string contains one [ and ] each, then...

1. Use componentsSeparatedByString to split the source string with [.
2. Use componentsSeparatedByString to split the result (objectAtIndex:0) above with ].